# Group values from the same row-dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, row, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with several values in a row that are related and I would like to group them. Each number code "GO_" corresponds with a description. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame("Protein"= c("a", "b"),"ID"= c("F_GO_0015;F_glycine","F_GO_00037;F_GO_00041;F_mRNA;F_cysteine"))
  df
```

```
Protein     ID
1       a F_GO_0015;F_glycine
2       b F_GO_00037;F_GO_00041;F_mRNA;F_cysteine
```

```
df.new <-data.frame("Protein"= c("a", "b"),"ID"= c("F_GO_0015-F_glycine","F_GO_00037-F_mRNA;F_GO_00041-F_cysteine"))
  df.new
```

```
Protein ID
1       a    F_GO_0015-F_glycine
2       b    F_GO_00037-F_mRNA;   F_GO_00041-F_cysteine
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
vec <- c("F_GO_0015;F_glycine", "F_GO_00037;F_GO_00041;F_mRNA;F_cysteine")
vec
# [1] "F_GO_0015;F_glycine"                     "F_GO_00037;F_GO_00041;F_mRNA;F_cysteine"
```

We can split them by `;`,

```r
str(strsplit(vec, ";"))
# List of 2
#  $ : chr [1:2] "F_GO_0015" "F_glycine"
#  $ : chr [1:4] "F_GO_00037" "F_GO_00041" "F_mRNA" "F_cysteine"
```

From which we can double-`paste` portions of the vectors:

```r
sapply(
  strsplit(vec, ";"),
  function(z) paste(paste(z[seq_len(length(z)/2)], z[-seq_len(length(z)/2)], sep = "-"), collapse = ";")
)
# [1] "F_GO_0015-F_glycine"                     "F_GO_00037-F_mRNA;F_GO_00041-F_cysteine"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how could I include it in the dataframe?

Comment: `df$ID <- sapply(strsplit(df$ID, ";"), function(z) ...)`